# Backbone bizzare syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, frontend

I was really struggling to understand the syntax of the Backbone but failed miserably, look at the following code:

```
var MenuItemDetails = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

I have looked at the source code of the Backbone.js and found the following declaration of Backbone.Model

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
  var attrs = attributes || {};
  options || (options = {});
  this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
  this.attributes = {};
  if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
  if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
  attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));
  this.set(attrs, options);
  this.changed = {};
  this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

as I understand `var Model` is now a function, which will work as constructor. What I don't understand is:

1. we are not calling `var myModelObject = new Model()` or `var myModelObject = new Backbone.Model()`. Instead we are calling `Backbone.Model.extend()`. How on earth does this work as a constructor?
2. This call `Backbone.Model.extend()` breaks my mind. We are calling a function called `extend` on another function called `Backbone.Model`

Comment: Functions are objects and can have properties just like any other object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused between two different objectives:

`var myModelObject = new Backbone.Model()` or `var myModelObject = new MyCutomModel()` is used to to create a new instance of a model.

`Backbone.Model.extend()` is used to create your own custom module, so your code would look something like this:

```
var MyCutomModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        // Overwrite the default initialize function
    }, 
    customMethod: function () {
        // Write your own custom method that you can use in this model
    }
});
```

The extend method is not part of JavaScript. There's no such thing as a default `extend` method that is native to Javascript.

However, many libraries have their own `extend` methods and it's very common for libraries and individuals to write their own `extend` methods (what they do might be quite different though, `$.extend`, `_.extend`, `Backbone.Model.extend` are all different; although `$.extend` and `_.extend` are pretty similar).

Backbone has its own custom `extend` methods ([Read the Source Code](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1648-L1685)), which basically adds properties and methods to the object and to its prototype.

Once you create an instance, of `MyCutomModel`, you can use the methods you've defined for it in your `extend`.

```
var my_custom_model = new MyCutomModel();
my_custom_model.customMethod();
```

To answer the second part of your question: Yes, it's a little confusing. It's JavaScript!

`Backbone.Model` is a function, but what that function does is return an object. That function can also have methods that you can call on that function. Look at the following code taken from this [stackoveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521833/javascript-add-method-to-object):

```
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype.bar = function(){}
var x = new Foo()
x.bar()
```

Since JavaScript functions are actually a [`Function` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), it's perfectly ok in JavaScript for a function to return something and to also have a method.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on extend method? Am I right that `extend` method is not a part of backbone.js but rather a part of JavaScript itself? When we call `Backbone.Model.extend()` do we take the function `Model` and add additional methods to the object which represents the function `Model`?

Comment: @RustamIssabekov no, `.extend()` is definitely not part of JavaScript. It's something that's part of Backbone.

Comment: I hope my question answers that. `.extend()` is a method that belongs the the `Bacbone.Model` object. This object just so happens to be a function, and when you call the function directly, that function gets executed.

Comment: `$.extend` and `_.extend` are actually quite similar, the `Backbone.X.extend` functions are quite different from both though.