# JS: how to add methods to an instance of an object?

Tags: javascript

here is my html

```
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    <script src="help.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    game = new Game();
    game.start();
})
</script>
```

game.js:

```
var Game = function() {
    this.start = function() {
        console.log('start');       
    };

};
```

help.js

```
Game.help = function() {
    alert('help');
}
```

however game.help() raises an error

What is wrong ? and how to fix it ?

Error: help is undefined

Comment: what error does it raise?

Comment: You added `help` to `Game` not to `game`. Try `Game.prototype.help = function() { ...}`

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521833/javascript-add-method-to-object

Comment: The best way to create method is to use `Game.prototype.start = function(){}`. It will make just one function which will be written in Game's prototype instead of thousands functions you will create: one function for every Game's instance.

Comment: You need prototypical inheritance, as stated by Matt Burland.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, `Game.help` will attach a function to the function `Game`, *not* to instances of the `Game` object.

That is, `Game.help = function () { ... }` will allow `Game.help()` but not `new Game().help()`. This is the equivalent of a static method in most OO languages.

What you *can* do, but isn't very idiomatic, is to change `help.js` to:

```
Game.prototype.help = function () {
  ...
}
```

This will attach the function as a method, so any instance of `Game` can have `help()` called on it.

Extending a class' prototype from another module(/file) is kind of sketchy, though, since it adds an implicit dependency (implicit preventing the browser from enforcing it, often leading to errors later when you forget about the dependency and change something that looks unrelated).

Until the ES7 extension methods proposal is finalized (and ES7) lands, you may want to consider using helper methods that take their scope as the first parameter:

```
help(game, ...) {
  alert('help for ' + game.name);
}
```

This is still less than ideal, but somewhat safer.