# Javascript: instance method returning NAN

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects, nan

I'm having some trouble with thh following code:

```
var num_passengers;


function vehicleConstructor(name, num_wheels, num_passengers)
{
    var vehicle = {};
    vehicle.name = name;
    vehicle.num_wheels = num_wheels;
    vehicle.num_passengers = num_passengers;

    vehicle.makenoise = function() {

    }
    return vehicle;
}

var bus = vehicleConstructor("bus", 5, 10);

bus.pickUpPassengers = function(toPickUp){
    num_passengers += toPickUp;
    return num_passengers;
} 


 bus.pickUpPassengers(5);
```

I’ve added a global num_passengers for the pickUpPassengers() to avoid it being undefined.

However, I’m still receiving a NAN for the pickUpPassegers method of the bus instance.

Is it a matter of scoping or definition?

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/13522017

Comment: `num_passengers` is never initialized with a value. What you are referencing inside `pickUpPassengers` is the global variable you defined at the top, not the vehicle instance property you added to the object in `vehicleConstructor`.

Comment: `num_passengers` is undefined.

Comment: inside `bus.pickUpPassengers()` `this.num_passengers` is the value bound to the `bus` instance if thats what your looking for ... (i.e would return 15)

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of `num_passengers` definition.
You should init it as a number at the beginning:

```
var num_passengers = 0;
```

But if you want to change value of `num_passengers` of your `bus` Object, you should use `this` and throw out first definition of `num_passengers`:

```
bus.pickUpPassengers = function(toPickUp){
    this.num_passengers += toPickUp;
    return this.num_passengers;
}
```

Comment: This would be true if the intention is for all instances of a vehicle to share a single cumulative value, I don't think thats the case.

Answer (score 1):

Just one small problem on finding the current instance. You simply need to define which instance you need for num_passengers with 'this'.

Also, This way you do not need the global variable for num_passengers, which means you can have multiple instances( car, bus, and motorcycle) at the same time. This will potentially avoid future problems.

```
function vehicleConstructor(name, num_wheels, num_passengers)
{
    var vehicle = {};
    vehicle.name = name;
    vehicle.num_wheels = num_wheels;
    vehicle.num_passengers = num_passengers;

    vehicle.makenoise = function() {

    }
    return vehicle;
}

var bus = vehicleConstructor("car", 5, 10);

bus.pickUpPassengers = function(toPickUp){
    this.num_passengers += toPickUp;
    return this.num_passengers;
}
```

Comment: I would get rid of that confusing initial & unneeded `var num_passengers;`

Comment: Thanks @AlexK.  Good call on that fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would write your code:

```
function Vehicle (name, options) {
  this.name = name
  this.wheels = options.wheels
  this.passengers = options.passengers
}

Vehicle.prototype.makeNoise = function () {
  console.log('vroom')
  return this
}

var bus = new Vehicle('bus', { wheels: 4, passengers: 10 })

bus.pickUpPassengers = function (toPickUp) {
  this.passengers += toPickUp
  return this
}

bus.pickUpPassengers(5)
```

This uses JavaScript's prototypical inheritance, which can be used like classes in other languages. Constructors start with a capital letter (by convention) and are called with `new`. Using prototypes also means that you don't define methods like `makeNoise` every time you create a new vehicle, instead all the vehicles refer back to the prototype.

I've also used `return this` at the end of the methods as it allows chaining:

```
// Without chaining:
foo.bar()
foo.baz()
foo.qux()

// With chaining:
foo.bar().baz().qux()
```

The Vehicle constructor also takes the numbers of wheels and passengers in an options object, which makes it easier to read and understand what the numbers are for.

---

With ES6 it would look like this:

```
class Vehicle {
  constructor (name, { wheels, passengers } = {}) {
    this.name = name
    this.wheels = options.wheels
    this.passengers = options.passengers
  }
  makeNoise () {
    console.log('vroom')
    return this
  }
}

class Bus extends Vehicle {
  constructor (options) {
    super('bus', options)
  }
  pickUpPassengers (toPickUp) {
    this.passengers += toPickUp
    return this
  }
}

const bus = new Bus({ wheels: 4, passengers: 10 })
bus.pickUpPassengers(10)
```

(Here I chose to make `Bus` a subclass of `Vehicle` because it's easier with ES6. It also helps you if you want to create more than one bus.)