# JavaScript function after object is created

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a context function type that is defined as below:

```
var Context = function () {

    this.run = function () {
        method1();
        method2();
    }

    var method1 = function () {
    }
}
```

As it is clear in the definition, **method2** is not defined in the context. I need every instance of Context passes its implementation of this method.

```
var c = new Context();

// This does not work! because the call in run() function 
// is not this.method2();

c.method2 = function () {
    alert("injected method2");
};

c.run();
```

I need to keep **method2()** in **run** without use of *this* object i.e. *this.method2();*

Any solution?

Comment: Why don't you use callback function as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can define `method2` before creating `Context` it will work no problem:

```
function method2() {
  alert(2);
}

var c = new Context();
c.run();
```

Comment: Note that my answer is basically equivalent to @Stephan Bijzitter's, since in the global scope defining a function attaches (hoists) it to the `window` scope. His answer will not work however if you are say, inside a React module.

Comment: Thanks that solves my problem. I can actually put it all in a self calling function to avoid any conflicts.

Comment: Although there's no need to define it _before_, as hoisting will make it available anyway

Comment: Very true, so long as it's defined as `function x()` instead of `const x = function()`

Answer (score 1):

You can add `method2` to the `window` object instead of the `c` object, in which case it will work.

Note that this is a clear indicator of poor design. You should probably look into doing this differently.

Answer (score 0):

Callback approach:

```
var Context = function (callback) {

    this.run = function () {
        method1();
        if(callback) callback();
    }

    var method1 = function () {
    }
}

var c = new Context(function () {
    alert("injected method2");
});

c.run();
```

Comment: I cannot accept this, because you changed the definition of **Context**.

Comment: @Hasan Do you mean that you want to add prototype? Context.prototype.method2 = function() {}?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521833/javascript-add-method-to-object

Answer (score 0):

If you change your run method to the following it should work as expected

```
this.run = function () {
    method1();
    this.method2();
}
```

**UPDATE:** I just realized it looks like you want to be able to do this on all instances of Context objects.  In that case you would also need to define method2 on `Context.prototype` and not just on `c`

```
Context.prototype.method2 = function () {
    console.log("injected method2dfd");
};
```

Comment: I explicitly mentioned I don't want to do that in the question.