# How can I convert a toTitleCase function into a "native" JavaScript string method?

Tags: javascript

I have created a function that changes a phrase to title case:

```js
function toTitleCase(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  let x = arr.map(word => {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  });
  return x.join(' ');
}

console.log(toTitleCase("A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!"));
```

I wish I could make this function work like the native `toLowerCase()`, by changing it to the string, not passing the string as a parameter:

```
console.log(("A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!").toTitleCase());
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521833/javascript-add-method-to-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript add method to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521833/javascript-add-method-to-object)

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392035/add-method-to-string-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the string prototype.

```js
String.prototype.toTitleCase = function() {
  let arr = this.split(' ');
  let x = arr.map(word => {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  });
  return x.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the function to `String.prototype`:

```js
String.prototype.toTitleCase = function() {
  const arr = this.split(' ');
  const x = arr.map(word => {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  });
  return x.join(' ');
}

console.log(("A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!").toTitleCase());
```

But that's [pretty bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223449). A standalone function is better.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is assign it to `String.prototype` although that is is discouraged.